# Order of fd allocation in process substitution

Tags: bash, file-descriptors, process-substitution

Inspired by this answer https://security.stackexchange.com/a/166645
I am wondering the reason behind the weird ordering when I run these commands:

```
root@6cb8704148bf:/usr/app# echo <(printf "111")
/dev/fd/63
root@6cb8704148bf:/usr/app# echo <(printf "111")
/dev/fd/63
root@6cb8704148bf:/usr/app# echo <(printf "111") <(printf "222")
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
```

This seems somewhat normal so far. Then I was wondering what happens if you keep going down to 0.

```
root@6cb8704148bf:/usr/app# echo <(printf "111") <(printf "222") <(printf "222")  <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222")  <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222")  <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222")  <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222") <(printf "222")
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 /dev/fd/61 /dev/fd/60 /dev/fd/59 /dev/fd/58 /dev/fd/57 /dev/fd/56 /dev/fd/55 /dev/fd/54 /dev/fd/53 /dev/fd/52 /dev/fd/51 /dev/fd/50 /dev/fd/49 /dev/fd/48 /dev/fd/47 /dev/fd/46 /dev/fd/45 /dev/fd/44 /dev/fd/43 /dev/fd/42 /dev/fd/41 /dev/fd/40 /dev/fd/39 /dev/fd/38 /dev/fd/37 /dev/fd/36 /dev/fd/35 /dev/fd/34 /dev/fd/33 /dev/fd/32 /dev/fd/31 /dev/fd/30 /dev/fd/29 /dev/fd/28 /dev/fd/27 /dev/fd/26 /dev/fd/25 /dev/fd/24 /dev/fd/23 /dev/fd/22 /dev/fd/21 /dev/fd/20 /dev/fd/19 /dev/fd/18 /dev/fd/17 /dev/fd/16 /dev/fd/15 /dev/fd/14 /dev/fd/13 /dev/fd/12 /dev/fd/11 /dev/fd/10 /dev/fd/9 /dev/fd/8 /dev/fd/7 /dev/fd/6 /dev/fd/5 /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/64 /dev/fd/65 /dev/fd/66 /dev/fd/67 /dev/fd/68 /dev/fd/69 /dev/fd/70 /dev/fd/71 /dev/fd/72 /dev/fd/73 /dev/fd/74 /dev/fd/75 /dev/fd/76 /dev/fd/77 /dev/fd/78 /dev/fd/79 /dev/fd/80 /dev/fd/81 /dev/fd/82 /dev/fd/83 /dev/fd/84 /dev/fd/85 /dev/fd/86 /dev/fd/87 /dev/fd/88 /dev/fd/89 /dev/fd/90 /dev/fd/91 /dev/fd/92 /dev/fd/93 /dev/fd/94 /dev/fd/95 /dev/fd/96 /dev/fd/97 /dev/fd/98 /dev/fd/99 /dev/fd/100 /dev/fd/101
```

Why does it go like:

```
63
..
5
3
4
64
...
```

Can anyone explain this ordering?

Comment: I do know that `fd0`, `fd1`, and `fd2` are all reserved for stdin, stdout, and stderr respectively.  I am not aware of any standard for default assignation of the other numbered file descriptors.  It's possible (and this is speculation) that it is counting down from a presumed high of 64 so as not to collide with the possibly-more-likely-to-be-manually-invoked ones starting at 3 and going up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [the code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c?h=bash-5.2#n6502), you'll see:

```c
  /* Move the parent end of the pipe to some high file descriptor, to
     avoid clashes with FDs used by the script. */
  parent_pipe_fd = move_to_high_fd (parent_pipe_fd, 1, 64);
```

The idea being that fds 0 to 9 in sh are reserved to the user who can do `cmd < x > y 2> z ... 9> ...`. So the shell tries to use fds outside of that range for its all internal FDs. That's not limited to process substitution, you can see it's also used for co-processes for instance:

```
$ bash -c 'coproc :; echo "${COPROC[@]}"'
63 60
```

While in some other cases like the saving of file descriptors when redirecting builtins or the `{fd}>...` from zsh, it just tries to get a fd >= 10 (using `fcntl (fd, F_DUPFD, SHELL_FD_BASE)`):

```
$ bash -c 'exec {fd}</dev/null; echo "$fd"'
10
```

The [code for that `move_to_high_fd()` function](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/general.c?h=bash-5.2#n633), looks for the first free fd below the `maxfd` passed as argument (here 64) and that is greater than `3`, and move the fd to that. If it fails, if fds 4 to 63 are all in use, then the fd is not moved, which explains why you get those 3, 4, 64.

Why it does it backward from a "high" value as opposed to getting the first free fd above 9 like zsh does I suppose is linked to the fact that bash actually lets the user use fds above 9 as an extension over the standard.

That code or similar was already there in 2.0 in 1996, though process substitution only started to use it in 2.0.1. Prior to that, process substitution was not moving fds, so you would likely get the same kind of problems as you get in ksh93¹ which doesn't move those fds:

```
$ ksh -c 'echo <(:)'
/dev/fd/3
$ ksh -c 'exec 3< <(echo test); cat <&3'
ksh: 3: cannot open [Bad file descriptor]
```

Which you work around by *reserving* the fd before performing the process substitution:

```
$ ksh -c 'exec 3<&0 3< <(echo test); cat <&3'
test
```

Current `bash` versions have the same problem in:

```
$ bash -c 'exec 63< <(echo test); cat <&63'
bash: line 1: 63: Bad file descriptor
$ bash -c 'exec 63<&0 63< <(echo test); cat <&63'
test
```

Its `move_to_high_fd()` doesn't guard against clashes, it only kind of works on  the assumption that people are going to prefer using low fd numbers.

Why 64 I don't know. The `CWRU/changelog` in bash-2.05b mentions:

```
subst.c
        - in process_substitute, call move_to_high_fd with `maxfd' parameter
          of -1 instead of 64, so move_to_high_fd will use its maximum
```

In between the release of `bash-2.05b-beta1` and `bash-2.05b-beta2`, but it looks like it was reverted before 2.05b was released.

That `move_to_high_fd()`, according to changelogs was introduced between bash-2.0-alpha4 and bash-2.0-beta1 with this changelog entry:

> general.c
>
> - new function: move_to_high_fd(fd), which tries to move FD to a
>   file descriptor close to the allowed maximum, returning the new
>   fd and closing the old one (or returning the old one if something
>   goes wrong)

Initially not taking a `maxfd` argument, but moving to the highest determined allowed value (capped to 256). The `maxfd` was added between bash-2.01-alpha1 and bash-2.01-beta1 with:

> general.c, general.h
>
> - move_to_high_fd now takes a third argument: the highest fd at which
>   to start looking.  If that's less than 20, the maximum number of
>   open files as returned by getdtablesize() is used (which is what
>   it did before this)
>
> jobs.c, shell.c, subst.c
>
> - changed calls to move_to_high_fd appropriately

But no indication as to why it was sometimes used with 64 as the `maxfd`. As a guess, maybe some systems didn't have `/dev/fd/n` with n greater than 63.

---

<sup>¹ Process substitution was introduced by ksh in the mid-80s but you couldn't use a process substitution as the target of a redirection back then. That was changed relatively recently in ksh93.</sup>

Comment: amazing answer!